# Flutter, how to get gallery image and set as Avatar?

Tags: flutter, image

I am still new to Flutter, can someone tell how to select an image as Avatar? Also, I would like to show the same image when user comes back to the app next time, should I only store the path in local file will do?

part of my code:

```dart
XFile? headImage;
```

```dart
child: ListView(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  children: [
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        selectImage();
      },
      child: UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.teal),
        accountName: Text(
          globals.userName,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        accountEmail: Text(
          '',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
          // backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/cookie.JPG'),
          backgroundImage: Image.file(File(headImage.path)).image,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

```dart
Future<void> selectImage() async {
  ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  headImage = image;
  print(headImage?.path);
}
```

I can get `headImage?.path`, but I can't assign back to the Avatar but get error:

```
Property 'path' cannot be accessed on 'XFile?' because it is potentially null.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add variable for image:

```
File? _avatarFile;
```

set data for `_avatarFile` after image picked:

```
Future<void> selectImage() async {
  ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
 
  setState((){
    _avatarFile = File(image.path ?? '');
  });
}
```

Now you can use _avatarFile for FileImage();

```
currentAccountPicture: _avatarFile != null
          ? CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
              backgroundImage: FileImage(_avatarFile!),
            )
          : const CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/cookie.JPG'),
            ),
```

Comment: the line _avatarFile = File(image.path ?? ''); gives an error:
Property 'path' cannot be accessed on 'XFile?' because it is potentially null.
I tried image?.path, it works but then I can't save the value to local file as it is potentially null.

Comment: check `if(image.path == null) return;` when image.path null we will not save to local file, empty data is inevitable

Comment: it doesn't allow me to access image.path

Comment: provider some images for question, I can't figure out what you need

Comment: Thanks, I am done with if (image !=null){ saveFile(image.path);}